# Changing starting number of User ID

Tags: customization, database, users, user-registration, id

I've got a client who would like their online user registration to match their current database. Thus they'd like their wordpress sign ups to start with 00100, I can't seem to find a plugin that allows this, is there anyway of adjusting the database to achieve this?

Comment: That's interesting. Would it take the form of user ID = 1 = `00101` or `001001`? Seems like it'd be easy to reconcile the 2 databases or are they wanting to merge the databases or something else?

Answer (score 0):

At the db level you can add one more field to wp_users and create trigger that fills this field on row create. That said, this can cause issues with wp updates in the future.

Another option would be to create view that shows rows from wp_users and calculates that special Id for you. Afterwards, you can run queries against the view and do not interfere directly with the user table.